# Pixel to image using python

Tags: python, csv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pixel

I've seen some code on the internet for the conversion of .csv file to images. But I couldn't understand some part of the code. Could someone help me out?

Here's the code

```
# convert string to integer
def atoi(s):
    n = 0
    for i in s:
        n = n*10 + ord(i) - ord("0")
    return n


df = pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv')
mat = np.zeros((48,48),dtype=np.uint8)
for i in tqdm(range(len(df))):
    txt = df['pixels'][i]
    words = txt.split()
    
    # the image size is 48x48
    for j in range(2304):
        xind = j // 48
        yind = j % 48
        mat[xind][yind] = atoi(words[j])

    img = Image.fromarray(mat)
```

Here fer2013 consists of grayscale images. Is there any other method to write it easily? I couldn't understand the part with #the image size is 48x48. Why would they give xind = j//48 and yind = j%48. Can someone explain this part?

**This is not the whole code.

Comment: "the image size is 48x48" is simply a statement of fact about the images in the CSV file.  The following math is a conversion between 1D indexes into the line of text (0..2303) to 2D indexes into the resulting image (0..47 x 0..47).  The `atoi()` function given here is silly, Python has a built-in `int()` function for this.

Comment: @jasonharper could you please tell me why xind is j//48 and yind is j%48. What's the difference here between // and %.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity consider a 4 x 4 image data

```
words = [str(i+1) for i in range(16)]
```

The following will do the same as the code below `# the image size is 48x48`

```
[list(map(int, words[i:i+4])) for i in range(0,16,4)]
```

It simply converts a 1d array of strings to a 2d array of integers